# Is the order of evaluation with comma operator & assignment in C predictable?

Tags: c, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

Recently cppcheck raised an error in some C code, that has the structure:

```
((void)(value_prev = value), value = new_value())
```

In most cases this can be split onto 2 lines, however there are some cases this is useful to have in a single statement.

In practice I found this works with popular compilers (GCC/Clang/MSVC), which don't give any warnings *(even with warning levels set to their highest)*.

---

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_next(int i);

int main() {
    int i = 0, i_prev = 10;
    do {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    } while ((void)(i_prev = i),
             (i = get_next(i)) != 10);
}
```

CppCheck 1.73 *(latest at time of writing)* gives an error with this code:

```
(error) Expression '(void)(i_prev=i),(i=get_next(i))!=10'
depends on order of evaluation of side effects`
```

While the code could be changed to quiet the warning, is the order really undefined?

Comment: Could it be that get_next(i) is a macro, like #define getnext(i) i++ ?

Comment: No, in this case its defined as a function, cppcheck gives the error on this code without any modifications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order is defined, because there is a sequence point between them.  See ISO/IEC 9899 6.5.17:

> The  left  operand  of  a  comma  operator  is  evaluated  as  a  void
>   expression;  there  is  a sequence point after its evaluation.  Then
>   the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value. 95)
>   If an attempt is made to modify the result of a comma operator or to
>   access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined.

They then give an explicit example:

> In the function call
>   `f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)`
>   the function has three
>   arguments, the second of which has the value 5.

I'm not entirely sure why CppCheck is flagging it.

Comment: @Alex If it is, then C99 borrowed it from C++.  I don't have any C specs earlier than C99 to compare.